# Error Context (latex)

Tags: luatex, context

Good morning, I have the following problem on 3 different computers: Compiling a preamble in TexWorks (Ver.0.6.8) using the ConTeXt(LuaTex) library, encounter the following error: The control sequence at the end of the top line of the error message was never \def'ed. You can just continue because I will forget everything that was undefined. mtx context | fatal error: return code: 1

I installed packages from both TexLive and MikTex.

The same code works however, on 2 other stations with TexWorks (Ver. 0.6.4) and only TexLive. (installed 2 years ago)

```
\section{Descrizione dell'opera.} Oggetto della presente
 relazione è il dimensionamento di un'apparecchiatura a
 pressione rientrante nell'ambito delle opere soggette alla
 normativa 2014/68/UE - Direttiva Apparecchi in Pressione 
(PED), in quanto sottoposta ad una pressione interna superiore
 a 0,05 \Mega\Pascal.

L'apparecchiatura è composta da una camera principale, a sua
 volta costituita da due fondi bombati (superiore ed inferiore)
 e da un fasciame cilindrico, con asse verticale.

\section{Codice di calcolo ed unità di misura.} Il codice di
 calcolo utilizzato nel dimensionamento volto a garantire la
 stabilità a pressione dell'apparecchiatura è la normativa EN
 13445, ed in particolare la normativa armonizzata UNI EN 13445.

Le unità di misura utilizzate nell'esecuzione dei calcoli sono
 le seguenti: 
\starttabulate[|l j2|c|]
 \NC dimensioni \NC \hfill \Milli \Meter \NC \FR%
 \NC forze \NC \hfill \Newton \NC \NR%
 \NC pressioni \NC \hfill \Mega \Pascal \NC \NR%
 \NC sforzi \NC \hfill \Mega \Pascal \NC \NR%
 \NC temperature \NC \hfill \Degrees \Celsius \NC \LR%
 \stoptabulate%
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

I installed the program on 3 computers, tried different libraries, different text editors, etc...

I expect to solve the problem, and generate the final PDF

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the output of the console: The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
\def'ed. You can just continue as I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 1

Comment: but no need to edit now :Max  Chernoff has shown the example you should have posted and explained the issue.

Comment: I don't know Latex, TexLive, etc. Where I work I found these files and I need to make them work, but I have no idea how to do it, could you help me with the code? What should I change in the code I posted? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To properly answer this, you should include an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/270600) (i.e., your code should include loading any packages as well as `\starttext`/`\stoptext`) and the full error message (which clearly identifies *which* command is undefined instead of making us guess).

I think that this is a proper MWE for the question:

```tex
\usemodule[units]

\startTEXpage[offset=1em]
    Test \Mega\Pascal\ test.
\stopTEXpage
```

Using TeX Live 2023, compiling with `context --luatex filename.tex` (MkIV) gives

```
[...]
system          > ConTeXt  ver: 2023.05.05 18:36 MKIV  fmt: 2024.1.27  int: english/english
[...]
modules         > 'units' is loaded
open source     > level 3, order 5, name '/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/modules/mkiv/m-units.mkiv'
resolvers       > lua > loading file '/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/modules/mkiv/x-mathml.lua' succeeded
units           > The units module is obsolete because functionality is built into the core.
[...]
system          | total runtime: 0.678 seconds
```

[image: output]

but compiling with `context filename.tex` (MkXL/LMTX) gives

```
[...]
system          > ConTeXt  ver: 2023.05.05 18:36 LMTX  fmt: 2024.1.13  int: english/english
[...]
modules         > 'units' is loaded
[...]
tex error       > tex error on line 4 in file ./context-units-error.tex: Undefined control sequence

<line 3.4> 
        Test \Mega
    \Pascal\ test.

1     \usemodule[units]
2     
3     \startTEXpage[offset=1em]
4 >>      Test \Mega\Pascal\ test.
5     \stopTEXpage
6     
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
\def'ed. You can just continue as I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 1
```

[image: output]

The issue here is that TeX Live 2023 now uses ConTeXt MkXL/LMTX. If you open `$TEXMFDIST/tex/context/modules/mkiv/m-units.mkiv`, the first 16 lines are

```tex
%D \module
%D   [       file=m-units,
%D        version=1997.03.19,
%D          title=\CONTEXT\ Extra Modules,
%D       subtitle=Scientific Units,
%D         author={Hans Hagen \& Ton Otten},
%D           date=\currentdate,
%D      copyright={PRAGMA ADE \& \CONTEXT\ Development Team}]
%C
%C This module is part of the \CONTEXT\ macro||package and is
%C therefore copyrighted by \PRAGMA. See mreadme.pdf for
%C details.

\ifcase\contextlmtxmode\else\endinput\fi

%D Best use the built in unit handle!
```

showing that the units module refuses to load with LMTX.

The proper solution here would be to switch to the new units syntax:

```tex
\startTEXpage[offset=1em]
    Test \unit{mega pascal} test.
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: output]

You can also run `context --luatex <filename>` instead of `context <filename>` to continue using the old MkIV version.

Finally, you can trick the units module into loading with LMTX, although I recommend against it since it's wildly unsupported:

```tex
\chardef\contextlmtxmode=0
\usemodule[units]
\chardef\contextlmtxmode=1

\startTEXpage[offset=1dk]
    Test \Mega\Pascal\ test.
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: output]

Comment: In the code I posted, how should I modify the code so that it is compatible with both the new version of TexLive and the old version?

Comment: @FabioDeReggi The "new" units syntax (i.e. `\unit{1 mega pascal}`) has been in ConTeXt for 10+ years I think, so it should also work with the older versions.

Comment: I don't know Latex, TexLive, etc. Where I work I found these files and I need to make them work, but I have no idea how to do it, could you help me with the code? What should I change in the code I posted? Thank you.

Comment: @FabioDeReggi If you have a bunch of old files, the easiest way to make it work would be to compile with `context --luatex <filename.tex>`. That'll force the old version of ConTeXt to be used. You'll miss out on a few new features, but it should be fully-compatible with any previous version of ConTeXt that you used.

Comment: Hi, Do you mean compiling from terminal? Because i use TeXworks to edit e compile the program. There are this options: pdfTeX
pddLaTeX
LuaTeX
LuaLaTex
XeTex
XeLaTex
ConTeXt(LuaTeX)
ConTeXt(pdfTeX)
ConTeXt(XeTeX)
BibTeX
I usually use ConTeXt(LuaTex) on the computer where the old version of TeXLive is installed, therefore I also tried to use it on the current computer but with the error I previously posted. (The same one he gives to you too)

Comment: @FabioDeReggi Somewhere in the settings, you should be able to change the exact command that each of those options run. I'd recommend changing `ConTeXt (LuaTeX)` to run `context --luatex` and add a new `ConTeXt (LMTX)` to run `context`.

Comment: In the settings of the program? (TexWorks) Or in another settings? Because I can't find any options to change. Thanks.

Comment: @FabioDeReggi Yes, in TeXWorks. There's almost certainly an option to change the compiler command line, but I don't use TeXWorks so I have no idea where to find it. Probably best to ask a new question for that.

Comment: What editor do you use? I may try the editor you use.

Comment: @FabioDeReggi I use Visual Studio Code, but I don't like any of the TeX extensions, so I either use [a custom task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) or just compile from the command line.